# Node.JS JavaScript fetching PDF contents prints PDFPage Formats instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdflib

I'm trying to fetch the text contents of the first page of a PDF file using NPM node module 'PDF-lib'.

However when I fetch the contents and print the results, I instead get an array of data that looks something like below;

Could you please help me spot the problem?

Thanks in advance!

The results I get after printing look like this. What I want to fetch are the actual text contents of the PDF page.

`PDFPage {`

`fontSize: 24,`

`fontColor: { type: 'RGB', red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 },`

`lineHeight: 24,`

`x: 0,`

`y: 0,`

`node: PDFPageLeaf {`

`dict: Map(8) {`

`[PDFName] => [PDFName],`

`[PDFName] => [PDFRef],`

`[PDFName] => [PDFDict],`

`[PDFName] => [PDFArray],`

`[PDFName] => [PDFRef],`

`[PDFName] => [PDFDict],`

`[PDFName] => [PDFName],`

`[PDFName] => [PDFNumber]`

`},`

`...`

`...`

`...`

The Code:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
const { PDFDocument } = require('pdf-lib'); // Library for reading PDF file
const fs = require('fs');

async function readDataset() {

    try { 

        // Get PDF Page
        const content = await PDFDocument.load(fs.readFileSync(resolve(`./app/assets/pdfs/np.pdf`)));

        // Get page contents
        const contentPages = content.getPages();

        let pageContent = contentPages[0];

        // Return data found on first page
        return pageContent;
    }

    catch (err) { 
        return err;
    }
    
}

// Read data from dataset
let dataset = await readDataset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not generally possible at present (2021 ) with this library see current [Limitations](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib#limitations) this info is also on the npm page at https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib#limitations

#1

> pdf-lib can extract the content of text fields (see PDFTextField.getText), but it cannot extract plain text on a page outside of a form field. This is a difficult feature to implement, but it is within the scope of this library and may be added to pdf-lib in the future. See #93, #137, #177, #329, and #380.

For future visitors always check the link above for current status.